# How to reuse user inputs from a loop

Tags: java, loops

I'm a newcomer to Java and have been asked to write a program for a questionnaire. It involved filling in yes/no answers and summarizing those answers in the form of percentages.

So far I've done the inputs and was hoping to use these yes/no inputs from the user as 1's/0's, summing up these inputs, divide totalQuestions from the results and multiply by 100 to get the percentage of yes's/no's for each question. But alas I've hit a wall!!

I've used a `for` loop to iterate the questions and participants and can see (when debugging) that the answers inputted are being assigned to my variables - `answer[1][0]`, `answer[1][1]`,.... which tells me the required values are there but how to take it to the next step?

I've put in something below the "// Questionnaire results" to show the desired result, however this doesn't allow the program to be easily adapted for more participants/questions.

I've pasted my program (so far) below and would greatly appreciate any suggestions/advise on how to get the desired result. There may be quicker/easier ways than I've done below, so apologies if my coding is poor - beginner status!
Thanks for any help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Questionnaire {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Yes or No:");

        // Participants
        final int PARTICIPANTS = 3;

        // Questions
        int numQuestions = 3;
        String[] question = new String[numQuestions];
        question[0] = "Have you ever shopped online? ";
        question[1] = "Do you use online banking? ";
        question[2] = "Do you have an email account? ";

        // Participant Loop
        int[][] answer = new int[PARTICIPANTS+1][numQuestions];
        for(int i = 1; i <= PARTICIPANTS; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Participant " + i);

            // Question Loop
            for(int j = 0; j < numQuestions; j++)
            {
                // Answer yes or no only
                boolean valid = false;
                do
                {
                    System.out.print(question[j]);
                    String userInput = in.next();
                    if(!userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") &&
                            !userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Please enter Yes or No");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        valid = true;
                        if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
                        {
                            answer[i][j] = 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            answer[i][j] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                } while(!valid);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        // Questionnaire results
        int q1Total = answer[1][0] + answer[2][0] +
                answer[3][0];
        int q1YesPercent = (q1Total*100)/PARTICIPANTS;

        int q2Total = answer[1][1] + answer[2][1] +
                answer[3][1];
        int q2YesPercent = (q2Total*100)/PARTICIPANTS;

        int q3Total = answer[1][2] + answer[2][2] + 
                answer[3][2];
        int q3YesPercent = (q3Total*100)/PARTICIPANTS;

        System.out.println("Survey Results\t\t\t Yes\t No");
        System.out.println(question[0] + "\t " + q1YesPercent +
                "%\t " + (100-q1YesPercent) + "%");
        System.out.println(question[1] + "\t " + q2YesPercent +
                "%\t " + (100-q2YesPercent) + "%"); 
        System.out.println(question[2] + "\t " + q3YesPercent +
                "%\t " + (100-q3YesPercent) + "%"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Can you be more specific on what you need help with?

Comment: You may use, for example `int[] totals = new int[numQuestions]` and iterate `answers` to fill it. You may also use `float[] qPercents = new float[numQuestions]`. (note that `qPercents` must be float)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might have rounding errors when dividing by `PARTICIPANTS` since you're using `int` variables. You could change `percent` to a double and use printf.

```
    // Questionnaire results
    System.out.println("Survey Results\t\t\t Yes\t No");

    for (int i=0;i<numQuestions;i++) {
            int total = 0;

            for (int j=0;j<PARTICIPANTS;j++)
                    total += answer[j][i];

            int percent = (total * 100) / PARTICIPANTS;

            System.out.println(question[i] + "\t " + percent + "%\t " + (100-percent) + "%");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Forager, this is what I was after. I did have to change the loop j=0 to j=1 to get the desired results. I would have put this loop the other way round, ie PARTICIPANTS before the numQuestions but on reading your code it's making more sense. Thanks ever so much :)))